# To test the convergence of $\int _0^1 \frac{\ln x}{(x^2 +1)}\, \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

The question is to  test the convergence of $$\int _0^1 \frac{\ln x}{(x^2 +1)}\, \mathrm dx $$
I tried comparison test or comparison it with a form of the Gamma Function or something, but was led to nowhere.

Comment: Note that this integral $=-\text{Catalan's constant}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$.

Comment: Since $\int_0^1 \ln x \, dx$ is convergent and $0 < \frac{1}{x^2+1}\leq 1$ the integral in question obviously is convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the substitution $x=\dfrac1t$, $\;\mathrm d x=-\dfrac{\mathrm d t}{t^2}$. The convergence of the given improper integral is equivalent to the convergence of
$$-\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln t\,\mathrm d t}{t^2+1}.$$
This one converges because
$$\frac{\ln t}{t^2+1}=o\biggl(\frac1{t^{3/2}}\biggr)\quad\text{near }\infty.$$

Comment: Can you explain the last step . The o() thing

Comment: That's asymptotic analysis. It means the quotient of the left-hand side  fraction by $\dfrac1{t^{3/2}}$ tends to $0$ at $\infty$. As the improper integral of $\dfrac1{t^{3/2}}$  converges, the former converges too (this works because the function takes positive values).

Answer (score 1):

In $[0,1]$, $\frac1{x^2+1}\in\left[\frac12,1\right]$ and therefore the convergence of your integral is equivalent to the convergence of $\int_0^1\log(x)\,\mathrm dx$. Now, doing $x=e^{-t}$ and $\mathrm dx=-e^{-t}\,\mathrm dt$, your integral becomes$$\int_0^{+\infty}te^{-t}\,\mathrm dt.$$ But, if $t\gg0$, $te^{-t}\leqslant e^{-\frac t2}$ and the integral $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-\frac t2}\,\mathrm dt$ converges. Therefore, your integral converges.